How to build project as is but minify every HTML, CSS and JS files
I have this project structure:

I need to build my project (red rectangle on image except .gitignore) as is keeping folder structure and all file names but I want to only HTML, CSS and JS files be minified without any uglifying
When I say minifying I mean to keep all names of variables, functions, classes as is but just remove comments and unnecessary spaces
Additionally I want to serve docs with hot reloading. I want to make some changes and when I switch to browser I want to see already minified versions
